# Background scrolling in libgdx Andriodjava

Tags: java, android

I am new to game development and try to scroll my background texture.
The now moves but texture becomes blur
here is snapshot of my error[Running game in andriod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Af2.jpg)

Here is my code

```
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture bg;
float bgx;
float speed = 0;
float scrollTimer = 2;
```

In create() method the code is

`batch = new SpriteBatch();
 bg = new Texture("background.jpg");`

In render method the code is

```
speed = 25;
speed = speed - scrollTimer;
bgx += speed;
batch.begin();

batch.draw(bg, bgx, 0, bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
batch().end();
```

Please tell what is missing